# FutureBuilder already built when new value returns

Tags: flutter

So I have a `StatelessWidget` with a `FutureBuilder`.
The problem is that my `Future` returns a cachedFile first and then gets the new data from my API. However I think my widget is then already built with the cachedFile and that's why it does not return the new data.
I'm using the Flutter Cache Manger package and my `Future` looks like this:

```dart
final response = await CacheManager().getSingleFile(url, headers: headers);
 if (response != null && await response.exists()) {
   final res = await response.readAsString();
   final finalList = MyData.fromJson(json.decode(res));
   return finalList;
 }
throw Exception();
```

I could probably convert my widget to a `StateFul` and then call `setState` at the end of my `Future`.

Any other ideas on how I could fix that?

Edit: I have now tried it with a `Stream` and `StreamBuilder`:
Stream:

```dart
  Stream<MyData> getStats() async* {

    final response = await CacheManager().getSingleFile(url, headers: headers);

    if (response != null && await response.exists()) {
      final res = await response.readAsString();
      final finalList = MyData.fromJson(json.decode(res));
      yield finalList;
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

and my `StreamBuilder`:

```dart
return StreamBuilder<MyData>(
      stream: getStats(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(
            "Please Check Your Internet Connection",
          );
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: Spinner(),
          );
        } else {
          return Text(snapshot.data.total)
        }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Futures can't pass many values, they will execute and return one value and then they are done.

If you need to pass multiple values, **you should use a `Stream` instead**. First your `Stream` emits the value in the cache, then later your `Stream` emits the value you got from your API.

After you modify your service to use a `Stream` instead of a `Future`, **modify your `build()` to use a `StreamBuilder`** instead of a `FutureBuilder`.

---

Edit:

For your edited code, the reason your screen doesn't updates is because you only `yield` once, you have to yield when you get the value from the cache and again when you get the value from your API.

You can also use a `StreamController` instead of `yield` if you prefer.

Comment: I tried using a `Stream` but it does not work. It saves the new data to cache but still shows the old data (I think because the `StreamBuilder` is already done building when it returns the new data). Do you have another idea?

Comment: It has to work, the problem should be on your code, your are not creating the `Stream` or the `StreamBuilder` correctly. Please post your code using `Stream`.

Comment: I have updated my question with the new code. Thanks a lot for looking into it!

Comment: I'm using the flutter cache manager package and it says for getSingleFile: 
"Get the file from the cache and/or online, depending on availability and age. [...] When a file is cached it is return directly, when it is too old the file is downloaded in the background. When a cached file is not available the newly downloaded file is returned."
I thought it would first return the cached file and then the new downloaded file (if there is). Am I missing something?

Comment: For that description and the code being a `Future` I can only conclude that the cache will return one file only, or the cached one or the downloaded one. Never return 2 files, a `Future` can't return twice, if it uses a `Future` then it will only return one item. I believe it will return the cached file (the first one it downloaded) until the file is too old, then it will download it again and recache it.

Comment: If you want a different behavior, you have to check on how to configure this library or use your own code.

Comment: If this answers your question, don't forget to accept and vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StreamBuilder` instead of `FutureBuilder`

```dart
StreamBuilder(
 stream: getMyData(),
 builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
   return Text('${snapshot.data}');
  }
  return Container();
})

Stream<MyData> getMyData() async* {
 yield cachedFile;
 final response = await CacheManager().getSingleFile(url, headers: headers);
 if (response != null && await response.exists()) {
   final res = await response.readAsString();
   final finalList = MyData.fromJson(json.decode(res));
   yield finalList;
 }
throw Exception();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It's the same thing, It saves the new data to the cache and then I have to change the screen and back or close the app and open it again to show the new data.